# Is moving big file between folders within one storage mount point can be considered lightweight?

Tags: linux, filesystems, android

My app operates with many video files on one storage (say, SD card).
I'd like to create subfolders and periodically move files between them.
As far as I understand, a `move` operation in Linux should be cheap
(just update File System Table and don't touch the subject file).

> Is it guaranteed `move` operation to be cheap and never turn out into
>   a `copy`?

PS: Specifically on Android I'm talking about [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)).

Comment: Probably, but if in doubt, you can always just create your own table that looks up filesystem paths using logical file identifiers.

Comment: Or, if in doubt, create symlinks (to absolute paths) and move *them* around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are on the same filesystem, yes. This is well explained [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998036/how-does-linuxs-mv-work-internally).